# Run Testcontainters on remote

Tags: c#, .net, docker, testcontainers

How can I start a container on a docker installed on remote server?

I tested `.WithDockerEndpoint("tcp://165.12.3.15:9563")` but the following error is occuring:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

```
public IntegrationTestFactory()
{
   MsSqlTestcontainer testContainer = new TestcontainersBuilder<MsSqlTestcontainer>()
        .WithDatabase(new MsSqlTestcontainerConfiguration
        {
            Password = "localdevpassword#123"
        })
        .WithDockerEndpoint("tcp://165.12.3.15:9563")
        .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server")
        .WithCleanUp(true)
        .Build();
   testContainer.StartAsync();

}
```

Comment: What you have done to ensure the remote server is listening and willing to accept connections through it's own firewall?

Comment: Actually nothing

Comment: This sounds like your Docker endpoint does not accept incoming connections. Please do not use `WithDockerEndpoint(...)` it is (will be) obsolete. To configure a different Docker endpoint use the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable ([docs](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/custom_configuration/)). It should probably be something like `DOCKER_HOST=http://165.12.3.15:9563`.